# How do you determine if a formula is satisfiable in Predicate Logic?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, model-theory, satisfiability

For example:

$ (\forall x)(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x))$

Are you suppose to invent your own Interpretation (domain, and giving the meaning to the predicates), and make it satisfiable under that Interpretation?

Attempt:

Interpretation *I*:

- Domain: $ \mathbb{N} $
- P(x) - "x is a natural number"
- Q(x) - "x is an integer"

*I* is a model of $ (\forall x)(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) $

Therefore, $ (\forall x)(P(x) \rightarrow Q(x)) $ is satisfiable.

Comment: Yes. More precisely, you have to construct your interpretation *such that* the formula becomes satisfied under it.

Comment: @lemontree Thank you. I've edited my question with an attempt now I know I'm on the right track. Could I have said P(x) and Q(x) are both "x is an integer"?

Comment: Correct, you got it. And yes, the statement with $P$ and $Q$ equal would also make the formula true. Just a terminological remark: Under the given interpretation the formula is true (or satisfi**ed**), and since such an interpretation exists, the formula is satisfi**able**.

Comment: Another detail I only now noticed: Since you chose the domain to be $\mathbb{N}$, rather than $\mathbb{Z}$, $Q$ will only contain natural numbers (a predicate can't encompass elements not in the domain), so $P$ and $Q$ are in fact the same set. If instead you choose $\mathbb{Z}$, then all $P$ are $Q$ but not all $Q$ are $P$. But both solutions work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From

> Yes. More precisely, you have to construct your interpretation such
> that the formula becomes satisfied under it. - @lemontree

It is clear how a formula can be satisfied.